# Is it possible to assign to Thread to one func and vice versa in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Im trying to learn abbout Threading in General and Python in specific 
I've seen Threads being spawned as single/multi

and like them being bound to only one function
is it how it works ?
can i get one thread for multiple functions
or (obviously yes) multiple threads for one function ?

let's also say that i got multiple functions defined in my script
and i want to assign a thread to each one , do i have to go through first part of this code 
or is there a another way to do it ?

```py
#example of single thread spawn
t = threading.Thread(target=somefunc,name="somename",args(arg1,arg1)


#example of multithread spwaning
for x in range(10)
     t = threading.Thread(target=somefunc,name="somename",args(arg1,arg1)
     t.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you specify as `target` when creating the `Thread` is what that thread will execute. So if you want to spawn multiple threads executing completely different things, you can do it with

```py
t1 = threading.Thread(target=do_first_thing, args=(arg,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=do_second_thing, args=(arg1, arg2))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

If you want multiple threads executing the same thing, you can do for example

```py
threads = []
for x in range(5):
  t = threading.Thread(target=do_thing)
  threads.append(t)
  t.start()
```

Or if you want multiple threads doing the same thing, just with different parameters

```py
threads = []
for name in ("stackoverflow", "Faboor", "sadbot"):
  t = threading.Thread(target=say_hello_to, args=(name,))
  threads.append(t)
  t.start()
```

However, you might be better of using `Pool` from the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) library, so that you don't have to manage your own thread life-cycle.